# I want to help Finder Overlay FullPath!(List Overlay)

Tags: objective-c, overlay, finder

```
class_addMethod(finder_class, @selector(FO_drawIconWithFrame:),
                    class_getMethodImplementation(self_class, @selector(FO_drawIconWithFrame:)),"v@:{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}");

    old = class_getInstanceMethod(finder_class, @selector(drawIconWithFrame:));
    new = class_getInstanceMethod(finder_class, @selector(FO_drawIconWithFrame:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(old, new);


// AND//

FO_drawIconWithFrame
{
...
NSString *path = [self objectValue];
...
}
```

i want to FullPath. but [self node] <- ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Did this work ?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSClassFromString(@"FINode") nodeFromNodeRef:[(TNodeIconAndNameCell *)self node ]->fNodeRef] previewItemURL];

NSString *path = [url path];
```